# Running MySQL server as slave for one DB and master for another

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have two MySQL server having master-slave replication for DB1. The slave server holds DB2. Because the slave server is not so powerfull I want to run analytics upon DB2 on the third server. Is it possible to have such setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title and question are ambiguous.  I'll give two answers.

- Do not try to replicate *some* tables in one direction and *other* tables in the other direction.
- It is perfectly fine to chain 3 (or more) servers chained together:

DB1 is a primary
DB2 is a replica of DB1 and also a primary
DB3 is a replica of DB2

Or you could have two Replicas hanging off one Primary.  That is,

DB1 is a primary
DB2 and DB3 are each replicas of DB1 -- Note: their relay logs will not necessarily be in sync with with each other; this is fine.

**Bidirectional replication** -- A dual-Primary setup involves each of two servers being both "Primary" and "Replica".  (This used to be called "dual-master".)  It is mainly used to allow for relatively rapid failover.

While you *could* use limitations on what is replicated (via binlog/replicate-do/ignore), you lose the failover feature.

One thing to note in *any* replication topology.  All writes are performed on *all* servers.  (Unless filtered out.)  My point is, that you cannot "scale writes" with normal replication.

**DB1 at Server1 -> DB1 at Server2 DB2 at Server2 -> DB2 at Server3**

So, there are 3 servers and at least 2 Databases?

On Server2, you may want "binlog_ignore = DB1" to avoid replicating *that* db to Server3.

Server2 is set up as a Primary (to Server3) and a Replica (of Server 1).

Comment: I'm not trying to replicate data bidirectional. What I want to do is:

DB1 at Server1 -> DB1 at Server2
DB2 at Server2 -> DB2 at Server3

Comment: @Ralfeus - I added more.  I would simply replicate everything and do different tasks (eg analytics) only on selected server(s).